# camelCase to lowercase html attribute conversion in Angular innerHtml binding

Tags: angular, angular2-template, string-interpolation, template-literals, property-binding

In my component I have a template literal string containing an HTML tag with an camelCase attribute in it:

```js
htmlString = `<mat-icon svgIcon="edit" ...></mat-icon>`;
```

This string gets assembled as a property of an object in an array forEach loop.

For several reasons in the template I need to output this in an innerHtml attribute within a *ngFor loop:

```html
<li *ngFor="let foo of foos" [innerHTML]="foo.htmlString"></li>
```

(This is a simplified code example of my implementation.)

I found out that in the output the `svgIcon` attribute is rendered in lowercase `svgicon`, see DOM inspector output:

```html
<li _ngcontent-qui-c96="">
  <mat-icon svgicon="edit"></mat-icon>
</li>
```

Bug or feature? Couldn't find any info on this behaviour. Thanks for any hint!

Comment: You realize this won’t work anyway right?

Comment: I've updated the description. It works, the innerHtml contents are properly put into DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are indeed all converted to lowercase by Angular, don't worry about that.

Also, the point you are raising as a side-effect is interesting and might need some explanation: you use `innerHtml` with an Angular component (`mat-icon`, it is not a standard HTML tag).

So, anyway, it will fail: a web browser does not know how to render a `mat-icon`.

For a `mat-icon` to be rendered, it must go through the Angular template engine: Angular will see `mat-icon`, and will pull the component definition/template, and render it in HTML terms (DOM), that a browser can understand.

Typically in your case, you should use:

```html
<li *ngFor="let foo of foos">
  <mat-icon [svgIcon]="foo.icon" ...></mat-icon>
</li>
```

And if your components are more complicated, you can explore using content projection with `ng-content`.

Comment: Thanks for he explanation! Meanwhile I found out that due to reduced complexity I don't need to do this string interpolation stuff and just do it the usual way in the template with literals :)